# How to update heroku timezones for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

The timezone for Venezuela changed recently from `-4:30` to `-4:00`, I have an app running in production that is behaving wrong because of this, I found the issue was postgresql has out of date timezones after running this command:

```
DATABASE=> SELECT utc_offset FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE name = 'America/Caracas';
 utc_offset 
------------
 -04:30:00
(1 row)
```

Running `g_config --configure` I get this option set: `--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo`

It's a production enviroment so I can't lose the data. How can I update these timezones in heroku postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I updated these timezones by removing the postgresql addon and adding it back.

First I turned on maintenance mode and created a backup:

```
heroku maintenance:on
heroku pg:backups capture
```

Then I removed the postgresql addon from heroku and added it back, and then I restored that backup:

```
heroku pg:backups restore b001 DATABASE_URL
heroku maintenance:off
```

Now the timezones are correctly updated:

```
billshl::DATABASE=> SELECT utc_offset FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE name = 'America/Caracas';
 utc_offset 
------------
 -04:00:00
(1 row)
```